# How to animate textview for example a word "Hello" in android studio without any button?

Tags: android-studio

so basically I want to animate hello which comes from down from the image and stop in the center of image as user launch the app. Can anyone help me. Plus my text view is on relative layout. And also is there any package do i need to import any packages in my main activity.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLGbd.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using GIF. And if you need help creating GIF, you can make a video of the animation, and then convert it to GIF by services available online.